# What adverb could I use before "apologizing" to mean "a lot"?

Tags: word-request, adverbs

What word could I use for someone who is apologizing a lot, for example in *I was ____ apologizing to them*?

I thought of *vigorously apologizing*, but it still feels like I’m forgetting a more fitting word.

Comment: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/my-humble-deepest-sincere-etc-apologies#my-humble-deepest-sincere-etc-apologies__1 and also https://www.macmillandictionary.com/collocations/british/apology#:~:text=apology%20collocations%20and%20examples%20%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8C&text=strongly%20felt%3A%20abject%2C%20fulsome%2C,please%20accept%20my%20sincere%20apologies.

Comment: A general-purpose option is "excessively". Not as tightly bound a collocation as "apologize profusely", but useful for many other verbs as well. (Note that, like "profusely", we would prefer to put this after the verb.)

Comment: I'm not sure the context. In a story, one might describe the action with more precision: "They stepped back as I kept apologizing." In an email, frankly, I'd probably write "I apologized to them a lot" and avoid formal diction (unless the context, again, calls for more formality).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The word you are looking for is *profusely*.

> Adverb
> [profusely](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/profusely) (*comparative* **more profusely**, *superlative* **most profusely**)
>
> 1. In great quantity or abundance; in a profuse manner.
>    *The run left him sweating profusely.*
>
> **Collocations**
> Some verbs commonly collocating with profusely:
>
> - *sweat* **profusely**
> - *apologise* **profusely**
> - *bleed* **profusely**
> - *thank* **profusely**
> - *cry* **profusely**

Pay particular attention to those "collocations".  The adverb "profusely" is almost never used outside of those examples (of course, you can also reverse the word order, so "profusely apologize" is perfectly fine).

Comment: And note that it follows the verb (we don't say "I was profusely apologising").

Comment: It seems ***to cry profusely*** has [only recently gained significant traction](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scattered+profusely%2Ccried+profusely%2Cprofusely+scattered&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). But [a century or two ago](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=profusely+scattered%2Cprofusely+cried%2Cscattered+profusely&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) we often said things were ***scattered profusely*** or ***profusely scattered***.

Comment: Thank you, the word order I was trying to fit it in must have been why I couldn’t remember it! Even if it works when reversed, it sounds much more natural after the verb.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I say
"I profusely apologised"

Comment: @KateBunting Of course you can say "I was profusely apologising"! It may not be as common, but [it's not rare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=profusely+apologising%2Capologising+profusely&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true).

Answer (score 9):

You could just say

> I was [deeply apologetic](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22deeply%20apologetic%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=APwXEdd-5alnU08_Ti70hhTM64oRsc6ffA:1686852460119&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1999&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiO2bGN78X_AhVzhv0HHVP8AlAQpwV6BAgKEBU&biw=1152&bih=637&dpr=2.5)

Comment: Or synonym: *profoundly* apologetic

Answer (score 5):

Try synonyms for *effusively*, *abjectly*, *obsequiously*, etc. Rather than an adverb, I might also use an adjective, or a different verb to express the same idea, e.g.,

- *I groveled, apologizing to them.*
- *I was abject in my apologies.*

Comment: What about “profusely”?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to emphasize how sincere you are being, instead of some of the alternatives which imply you might be overdoing it: *sincerely*, *remorsefully*, *genuinely*, *honestly*.

Comment: deeply, but I think the question is about the quantity, not the quality

Answer (score 2):

If you want to suggest the quantity of apology, rather than its vociferousness, then *copiously* may fit. It would probably fit better as *apologizing copiously* rather than the reverse order, or to give *copious apologies*.

[Copious - Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/copious) Yielding something abundantly

Comment: Copious suggest a large outpouring (tears, drama, claims of self-loathing, etc)  in a single apology. But in this case we want to signify a large number of individual apologies.

Answer (score 1):

The most common phrasing would be ‘I was apologizing profusely to them.’.

Note that ‘profusely’ preferentially comes after the verb it modifies, but it can also come before. It’s typical usage is relatively limited to being paired with a small handful of verbs (bleed, sweat, thank, and apologize are the four most common, cry is seen occasionally, and some others are occasionally used such as chastise, remonstrate, or expostulate). In may contexts, ‘profusely’ often bears an often negative connotation of extreme abundance or excess. The adjectival form ‘profuse’ is used a bit more freely than the adverb, but carries the same connotation of excess or overabundance.

‘apologizing vigorously’ would also be perfectly acceptable, and at least to me would not imply that the apologies were excessive, but more that they were instead enthusiastic and prompt, and possibly not quite genuine.

Depending on context, ‘apologizing vociferously’ may also work, though that usually implies either loud and obnoxious behavior, or incoherent babbling in an attempt to provide an apology, and would also at least for me carry a connotation of the apologies not being truly genuine.

Comment: Thank you so much, “profusely” was that word on the tip of my tongue that I couldn’t remember! And I appreciate the detailed explanations of the connotations.

Answer (score 1):

abundantly. I don't think it's used very abundantly, but it's just one of the options. Here is one example:

https://baylorlariat.com/2022/10/06/avoid-abundant-unnecessary-apologies/

Comment: thanks, I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Frequently:

frequently
[ free-kwuhnt-lee ]SHOW IPA

See synonyms for frequently on Thesaurus.com
adverb
often; many times; at short intervals.

[from dictionary.com]

Example:  He apologized so frequently, that his apologies meant little.

Also, if used before a noun, you may want an adjective, such as frequent:

Example:
This frequent apology stream was getting tiresome.

Comment: I don’t think this is what the OP meant, but the question is open to interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

To convey the meaning of "a lot" or "very much" in relation to apologizing, you can use the adverb "profusely." "Profusely" means in a large amount or to a great degree. It is often used to express sincere apologies or a deep sense of regret. Here's an example:

"I apologize profusely for any inconvenience caused."

In this sentence, "profusely" intensifies the apology, indicating that the speaker is expressing a strong and genuine sense of regret.

Other adverbs that can convey a similar meaning include "deeply," "sincerely," and "heartily." These adverbs can be used to emphasize the extent or sincerity of the apology. However, "profusely" is particularly associated with expressing apologies in a generous or abundant manner.

Remember that the choice of adverb may vary depending on the context and the level of formality. It's important to consider the specific tone and level of emphasis you want to convey when selecting the most appropriate adverb.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: All the suggestions listed in this answer, with the exception of *heartily*,  have already been mentioned on this page. In particular "profusely" was submitted over two days ago